# Adding class to cakephp checkbox input instead of div

Tags: html, class, cakephp, checkbox

I'm trying to put the

> class="answer_class"

inside all of my checkboxes, however it is creating a div instead and placing the checkboxes there. What should I alter in my code to do what I intend?

```
          $question['question_id'] => array(
            'type'=>'select',
            'multiple'=>'checkbox',
            'options'=> $answers,
            'class'=> 'answer_class',                    
            'label' => false
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass attributes to the options for your checkboxes:-

```
$question['question_id'] => [
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options'=> [
        'value' => 1, 'text' => 'Foo', 'class' => 'class1',
        'value' => 2, 'text' => 'Bar', 'class' => 'class2'
    ],                  
    'label' => false
];
```